# Session Unification not 'stitching'

Tags: javascript, session, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have GA and GTM configured so UserID is tracked, and all triggers are also associating the User with those events. This is all working fine and User Explorer is listing all User sessions (and all events) correctly.

I currently have 2 GA views:

- 1 standard/All Website Data
- 1 User report view (where only data from the Users' is displayed)

I have Session Unification set on, and using a 3-page process for testing:

**Home > Login > Members**

All 3 pages have the exact same GTM snippet and dataLayer attribute (including the exact same UserID variable). Although the UserID tag is firing on Page View within every single page, as you would assume, the UserID value is only assigned upon successful login within the 'Login' page, then the browser automatically redirects to the 'Members' page, e.

From the Tag Manager Preview console, I can see that the UserID value is being passed correctly when directed to 'Members'.

However, the sessions aren't 'stitching' together. Starting as a public/unidentified user, I access 'Home', which I can see in GA from the standard/All Website Data report view, where the session logs a hashed UserID (as this is not the User report view). The session correctly tracks everything from the initial 'Home' page, through to successfully logging in, and finally, viewing the 'Members' page. All of this within one session.

I was imagining the session would be the same when viewing the User report view, with the addition of the correctly assigned UserID variable to the session.  However, the session within the User report view begins only after the UserID has been assigned (the user has successfully logged in). No information prior to logging (such as viewing the 'Home' page or visiting the 'Login page) in is listed in this session, and I'm not exactly too sure why.

As I understand, from Google's documentation:

> Session unification is a User-ID setting that allows hits collected
>   before the User ID is assigned to be associated with the ID, so long
>   as those hits happen within the same session in which a specific ID
>   value is assigned for the first time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: If it matters, I'm testing all of this on a local environment.